# How to count items with unique/distinct values but for the same group in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, count, distinct

I'm trying to "Write a query to list all Fruit.Name who have at least 2 types in inventory in 2018."

I have code below which prints off all the items that have 2 or more. However, that is not what I want. For example, it is printing off Orange, Apple, Kiwi. When the actual result should just be Apple and Kiwi. This is because there are two Oranges of one type. Yet, I don't care if there is 2 of one type of fruit; I want results that are for fruits that have 2 or more different types like Granny Smith Apples and Red Apples. How can I get it to only give results where there are at least 2 distinct TypeIDs.

Ultimately the results should be a list of the overarching fruit (Apple) timestamped in 2018 and that have different types of fruit (Granny, Red, Green Apple...) in stock.

```
SELECT Fruit.Name
FROM Inventory
INNER JOIN Fruit
ON Inventory.ID = Fruit.ID
WHERE YEAR(Inventory.[Timestamp]) = 2018
GROUP BY Fruit.Name
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwPcD.png)

Comment: can you show how your table and rows look like? How about `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Fruit.Name) > 1` instead?

Comment: @JohnWoo I added a image with the table diagram. I also tried HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Fruit.NAME) > 1 but I received error messages saying syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Try `COUNT(DISTINCT TypeID)` instead of `COUNT(1)`

```
SELECT Fruit.Name
FROM Inventory
INNER JOIN Fruit
ON Inventory.ID = Fruit.ID
WHERE YEAR(Inventory.[Timestamp]) = 2018
GROUP BY Fruit.Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TypeID) > 1;
```

Comment: I've tried that and MS Access always gives me a "missing operator" error.

Comment: MS Access? Didn't get you.

Comment: @Aaron If you're running the SQL in MS Access, tag the question with that. Each RDBMS (if you can call MS Access that) has its own implementation of SQL.

Comment: @TT just tagged it with ms-access

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is not supported in MS Access SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `SELECT DISTINCT` subquery that you then run aggregate `COUNT`:

```
SELECT m.[Name]
FROM
   (SELECT DISTINCT f.[Name], i.TypeID
    FROM Inventory i
    INNER JOIN Fruit f
      ON i.FruitID = f.FruitID
    WHERE YEAR(i.[Timestamp]) = 2018
   ) m

GROUP BY m.[Name]
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```